# Change the background of an area containing already written text

Tags: delphi, canvas, colors, background

**(Delphi DX 10.3)**
I have a big blank (white) canvas (on a Tpanel's descendant) where I draw some text (using Textout(), let's suppose text is always black) and graphics (lines, rectangles, nothing of so complex).
**After** drawing, I need to change the color of the white background of some specific areas, from white to another colour.
The effect I want to reach is **much like an excel sheet** with coloured cells. In the attached example, all the columns are created blank (white) like "*value*" and "*difference*", then the yellow (*price*) and the red (*result*) columns have been coloured.
[image]

If I could fill in the areas **before** writing the text, I would use SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT) and get an optimal result. Unfortunately I need to fill in the areas **after** writing the text and graphics.
The first solution I thought of was pixel-by-pixel replacement (using the Pixels[] function), but it's dramatically slow and graphically unsatisfactory.

So my question is: **how can I color the background of an area containing already written text?**

Here a **Minimal Reproducibile Example**.
Button 1 execute pixels substitution, very slow and with unsatisfactory graphical result.
Button 2 fills areas after writing text, using SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT). Perfect result, but I can't do it.

```
program BK_mode;

uses
  Vcl.Forms,
  main in 'main.pas' {Form1};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

////////////////////////////////

```
unit main;

interface

uses Windows, Forms, SysUtils, Vcl.StdCtrls, UiTypes, System.Classes, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Graphics, Dialogs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
        btn_01: TButton;
        btn_02: TButton;
        procedure btn_02Click(Sender: TObject);
        procedure btn_01Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
        procedure write_text(canvas: TCanvas;x, y : integer;i_fontsize : smallint;const str_text: String;style : TFontStyles;bo_transparent : boolean);
        procedure switch_color(canvas : TCanvas;color_source, color_target : TColor);
        procedure prepare_example(bo_transparent : boolean);
  end;

var
    Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

const
    BASE_COLOR = clWhite;
    ALTERNATIVE_COLOR = clRed;

procedure TForm1.write_text(canvas: TCanvas;x, y : integer;i_fontsize : smallint;const str_text: String;style : TFontStyles;bo_transparent : boolean);
begin
    var lo_old_BK_color : TColor := canvas.Brush.Color;
    var lo_old_BK_mode := GetBKMode(canvas.Handle);
    if bo_transparent then SetBKMode(canvas.Handle, TRANSPARENT)
    else begin
        SetBKMode(canvas.Handle, OPAQUE);
        canvas.Brush.Color := BASE_COLOR
    end;
    canvas.Font.Color := clBlack;canvas.Font.Size := i_fontsize;canvas.Font.Style := style;
    TextOut(canvas.Handle, x, y, PChar(str_text), Length(str_text));
    if NOT bo_transparent then canvas.Brush.Color := lo_old_BK_color;
    SetBKMode(canvas.Handle, lo_old_BK_mode)
end;

procedure TForm1.switch_color(canvas : TCanvas;color_source, color_target : TColor);
begin
    for var x := 0 to clientWidth-1 do
        for var y := 0 to clientHeight - 1 do
            if (canvas.Pixels[x, y] = color_source) then canvas.Pixels[x, y] := color_target
end;

procedure TForm1.prepare_example(bo_transparent : boolean);
begin
    if bo_transparent then Color := ALTERNATIVE_COLOR else Color := BASE_COLOR;
    invalidate;
    application.MessageBox('Click me', 'Test');
    canvas.Rectangle(10, 10, 200, 100);
    canvas.MoveTo(10, 110);canvas.LineTo(200, 140);
    canvas.MoveTo(10, 140);canvas.LineTo(200, 110);
    write_text(canvas, 30, 30, 14, 'This is a text!', [], bo_transparent);
    write_text(canvas, 30, 60, 11, 'This is another text!', [fsBold, fsItalic], bo_transparent)
end;

procedure TForm1.btn_01Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    prepare_example(FALSE);
    switch_color(canvas, BASE_COLOR, ALTERNATIVE_COLOR)
end;

procedure TForm1.btn_02Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    prepare_example(TRUE)
end;

end.
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 283
  ClientWidth = 208
  Color = clWhite
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  DesignSize = (
    208
    283)
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object btn_01: TButton
    Left = 17
    Top = 161
    Width = 178
    Height = 51
    Anchors = [akLeft, akRight, akBottom]
    Caption = '1. write text and fill area'
    Font.Charset = ANSI_CHARSET
    Font.Color = clWindowText
    Font.Height = -16
    Font.Name = 'Arial'
    Font.Style = [fsBold]
    ParentFont = False
    TabOrder = 0
    WordWrap = True
    OnClick = btn_01Click
  end
  object btn_02: TButton
    Left = 17
    Top = 220
    Width = 178
    Height = 51
    Anchors = [akLeft, akRight, akBottom]
    Caption = '2. fill area then write text'
    Font.Charset = ANSI_CHARSET
    Font.Color = clWindowText
    Font.Height = -16
    Font.Name = 'Arial'
    Font.Style = [fsBold]
    ParentFont = False
    TabOrder = 1
    WordWrap = True
    OnClick = btn_02Click
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking for is simply not doable this way. You need to redraw the entire Canvas, drawing your backgrounds BEFORE drawing lines+text on top. Once you have drawn, you need a repaint to do everything over. DO NOT draw on a Canvas from outside of a Paint event.

Your example draws on a `TForm.Canvas`, so use the `TForm.OnPaint` event. For a `TPanel` descendant, override the virtual `Paint()` method instead. Either way, keep some variables with the desired settings, use those variable while drawing, and call `Invalidate()` after updating the variables and you want to trigger a repaint.

For example:

```pascal
unit main;

interface

uses Windows, Forms, SysUtils, Vcl.StdCtrls, UiTypes, System.Classes, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Graphics, Dialogs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    btn_01: TButton;
    btn_02: TButton;
    procedure btn_02Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btn_01Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FDrawTransparent : Boolean;
    FDrawColor : TColor;
    procedure write_text(ACanvas: TCanvas; x, y : integer; i_fontsize : smallint; const str_text: String; style : TFontStyles; bo_transparent : boolean);
    procedure prepare_example(bo_transparent : boolean; color_target : TColor);
  end;
    
var
  Form1: TForm1;
    
implementation
    
{$R *.dfm}
    
const
  BASE_COLOR = clWhite;
  ALTERNATIVE_COLOR = clRed;
    
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FDrawTransparent := False;
  FDrawColor := BASE_COLOR;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Canvas.Brush.Color := Self.Color;
  Canvas.Rectangle(10, 10, 200, 100);
  Canvas.MoveTo(10, 110);
  Canvas.LineTo(200, 140);
  Canvas.MoveTo(10, 140);
  Canvas.LineTo(200, 110);
  write_text(Canvas, 30, 30, 14, 'This is a text!', [], FDrawTransparent);
  write_text(Canvas, 30, 60, 11, 'This is another text!', [fsBold, fsItalic], FDrawTransparent);
end;

procedure TForm1.write_text(ACanvas: TCanvas; x, y : integer; i_fontsize : smallint; const str_text: String;style : TFontStyles; bo_transparent : boolean);
begin
  var lo_old_BK_color := ACanvas.Brush.Color;
  var lo_old_BK_mode := GetBKMode(ACanvas.Handle);
  if bo_transparent then
    SetBKMode(ACanvas.Handle, TRANSPARENT)
  else begin
    SetBKMode(ACanvas.Handle, OPAQUE);
    ACanvas.Brush.Color := FDrawColor;
  end;
  ACanvas.Font.Color := clBlack;
  ACanvas.Font.Size := i_fontsize;
  ACanvas.Font.Style := style;
  TextOut(ACanvas.Handle, x, y, PChar(str_text), Length(str_text));
  if NOT bo_transparent then ACanvas.Brush.Color := lo_old_BK_color;
  SetBKMode(ACanvas.Handle, lo_old_BK_mode);
end;    
    
procedure TForm1.prepare_example(bo_transparent : boolean; color_target: TColor);
begin
  FDrawTransparent := bo_transparent;
  FDrawColor := color_target;
  if bo_transparent then Color := ALTERNATIVE_COLOR else Color := BASE_COLOR;
  Invalidate;
  Application.MessageBox('Click me', 'Test');
end;
    
procedure TForm1.btn_01Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  prepare_example(False, ALTERNATIVE_COLOR);
end;
    
procedure TForm1.btn_02Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  prepare_example(True, BASE_COLOR);
end;    

end.
```

Comment: Thanks @Remy, of course you are right. I always use Paint to draw on Canvas, but in this case drawing directly would have saved me a lot of work. I will change my strategy, I will struggle more, but I will do a better job.